# How to convert string to datetime format?

Tags: python

How to convert a string to the specified datetime format ? For example:

```
str = 'Wed Mar 16 16:12:05 2016 +0800'
```

How can I convert it to :  `2016-03-16 16:12:05`?

Comment: what is `+0800` ??

Comment: thanks all , I used strptime + strftime  and it can works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime` library to convert datetime string into datetime object by `**strptime()**` and from datetime object to datetime strign by `**strftime()**`.

Format modes:

1. **%a**   Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.
2. **%d**   Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
3. **%b**   Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
4. **%H**   Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
5. **%M**   Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
6. **%S**   Second as a zero-padded decimal number.

[more details..](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

**Demo:**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> result_date =  datetime.strptime('Wed Mar 16 16:12:05 2016', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
>>> result_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 16, 12, 5)
>>> result_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2016-03-16 16:12:05'
```

**Note**:

1. Do not use reserved word as variable name. e.g. `srt`

Comment: many thanks for all of the kindly people's help :)

Answer (score 3):

Arrow is a great module for doing this in a very straightoforward way:
http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/

I perfer arrow to datetime as it is more succinct

For your specific example:

```
import arrow
date_str = 'Wed Mar 16 16:12:05 2016 +0800'
date = arrow.get(date_str,'ddd MMM D HH:mm:SS YYYY Z')
print date
2016-03-16T16:12:00.050000+08:00
>>>
```

Also, it's a bad idea to name strings

```
str
```

As this is taken, for the string type!

Why Arrow? I believe it has a nicer api than datetime:

```
>>> date.humanize()
3: u'2 days ago'
>>> date.resolution
4: datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 1)
>>> date.datetime
5: datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 16, 16, 12, 0, 50000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 28800))
>>> date.utctimetuple()
7: time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=8, tm_min=12, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=76, tm_isdst=0)
>>>
```

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted this, care to explain why?

Comment: That is the reason, why i like to write a comment 
instead of answer

Comment: wow, I do not understand that comment

Comment: there are peoples, who downvote your answer without  reason

Comment: ahh, I understand ye now. I like to answer, to share the knowledge, screw people who downvote without reason.

Comment: thanks to share this module , I'll learn it also^0^

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using **strptime** :

```
import datetime
myDatetime=datetime.datetime.strptime(My_string, format)
```

with format being such as `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` for Year month day, hour minutes seconds, so in your case it would be 'name of the day, month, day, etc ...

Comment: yes , I refer to the manual , and it can works ,many thanks